# Complex querying - generating list in date range. (complex windowing, recursive querying)

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

I'm using MYSQL.

```
 tax_year_end_changes | CREATE TABLE `tax_year_end_changes` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `date` date NOT NULL default '1970-01-01',
    `reason` enum('Fiscal_Year_End','Control_Change') collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT
     NULL default 'Fiscal_Year_End',
     `created_at` datetime default NULL,
     `updated_at` datetime default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `company_id` (`company_id`,`date`,`reason`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

This table contains a list of fiscal year ends for a company.  When the company fiscal year end changes, the table just has the new fiscal year end.  Default fiscal year ends are stored as from 1970.  Changes are stored effect from the change date.  Example data:

select company_id, date, reason from tax_year_end_changes;

```
1 1970-12-31 Fiscal_Year_End
1 2011-01-31 Fiscal_Year_End
3 1970-01-31 Fiscal_Year_End
4 1970-11-30 Fiscal_Year_End
```

Here, company 1 has fiscal year end of December 31 until 2010.  In 2011, FYE changes to January 31.  So for this company, the valid FYE are:

December 31, 2010
   January 31, 2011
   January 31, 2012
   . . .

I want to generate a list of valid FYE given a date range.  Specifically,

I'm given a starting date, and number of months.

I want to generate something like:

Use Case 1

```
Start Date: 2010-11-01
Number of Months: 3
```

company_id, month, tax_year_end_date

```
4 11 2010-11-30
1 12 2010-12-31
3 01 2011-01-31
1 01 2011-01-31
```

Use Case 2

```
Start Date: 2011-11-01
Number of Months: 3

company_id, month, tax_year_end_date

4 11 2011-11-30
3 01 2011-01-31
1 01 2011-01-31
```

Notes:  Notice how in Use case 2, 2011-12-31 doesn't appear for company 1 as that year is no longer valid.

Comment: Case 2 results doesn't make sense - why is a date from 2010 being included if using 2011 as a start date?!

Comment: You're right - I've fixed the use case.  Thanks.